# Constructing a JavaScript slide

Tags: javascript, beginner, performance

I am a newbie to native JavaScript and am pretty much coming to grips with the operators, etc. At the moment I am currently constructing a slide.

```
"use strict"; 

 var intSeconds = 3;

 function loadSlider(){

flickrImgsShown = 0; 
sliderImages = new Array(slides + 10);
sliderImages[0] = document.querySelector(".img");


    for (var i = 1; 1 < sliderImg; i++ ) {
        sliderImages[i] = document.querySelector(".img" + (i + 1));
        document.querySelector(".identifer" + i);
    }

    function next() {

        flickrImgsShown++; 
        if(flickrImgsShown == slides)
            flickrImgsShown = 0;
        transition();

        clearInterval(slideTimer);
        slideTimer = setInterval(timer, interSeconds * 1000);
    }

    function prev () {

        flickrImgsShown--; 
        if(flickrImgsShown == -1)
            flickrImgsShown = slides -1;
        transition();

        clearInterval(slideTimer);
        slideTimer = setInterval(timer, interSeconds * 1000);
    }

    slideTimer = setInterval(timer, intSeconds * 1000);

    function timer() {

        flickrImgsShown--; 
        if(flickrImgsShown == -1)
            flickrImgsShown = slides -1;
        transition();
    }

}
```

I am not a fan of the `getelementbyid`and `style.visibility` in my code. Is there a better method I can apply to call out an ID or change a style in the DOM?

Comment: @Nate_tyrone Then you have to use a javascript framework like jQuery.

Comment: You can use the new selector methods [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

Comment: It is actually a question, while they do ask for a code review that is not the purpose of the question posted.

Comment: I personally agree with @Andy: despite the question may be valid, the code is **apparently working**, therefore reviewing it or writing it in a different (clearer or shorter or whatever) way should not necessarely belong to stackoverflow but, instead, to codereview, where the user can even learn faster, shorter and easier ways to read and understand its own code.

Comment: I haven't actually been on the mentioned site, after reviewing I do have to agree it would aid the question poster in a constructive audit of their code.  This would certainly help in the learning process.  I do still believe that the question stands alone.  Perhaps if the question were edited to remove the request for review and code cut down to match the question it would fit here.

Comment: You can use jQuery or lightweight alternative e.g. [qwery](https://github.com/ded/qwery). Take a look at http://microjs.com/

Comment: I do not recommend to use Vanilla JS, JS without libs, if you want have good day. In general I suggest you to start [learning jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/). Next you can use [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to do awesome slideshow.

Comment: @aqquadro i know Jquery, however i have fallen into the trap of understanding Jquery but not completely understanding native JS completely, so when it comes to learning other libraries such as Angular and backbone it takes me slightly longer to pick up.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `document.getElementById()`. In fact, jQuery uses it! If you decide to use jQuery, you will be using the same method. So, cut the bloat and use it. It's a lot faster than `document.querySelector()`. And it's more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Your questions seem to have been answered (use jQuery), so here are a couple of small points regarding readability:

- be consistent with your variable names (eg `sliderImg` vs `flickrImgs`: one is plural, one singular, and in the rest of the code, you mainly use `flickrX`, except for the `sliderImg` one; I would prefer `sliderX` everywhere, because it doesn't seem to matter where the images come from).
- some variable names could be a lot better. Eg when reading `flickrImgs`/`sliderImg` I'm thinking it's an array of images (or image paths/names). But they are not, they are integers, so I would prefer `imageCount`/`imageSize`, and `currentSliderPosition`. `flickrDisplay` on the other hand seems to actually be a collection of images, so `sliderImages` would probably be a good name for it.
- your indentation is off, which decreases the readability of your code.
- your comments aren't all that helpful. `NOW AND NEXT FUNCTION`/`SLIDE TRANSITION` aren't really necessary, and `For each loop incrementing each slide by one` doesn't really help either (because that's exactly what the code already told me; If you do want to add a comment, it would be more helpful to explain what it means when a slide is increased.
- use curly brackets even for one line statements to increase readability and to possibly avoid bugs.
- `visiable` isn't a valid value for `visibility`, you probably meant `visible`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look the [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide) functions from jquery.

You can use them like this

```
$( "#id" ).show();
$( "#id" ).hide();
```

or just toggle the element's visibility

```
$( "#id" ).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can go about structuring your JavaScript and some of that will come down to style preferences.

Regarding the getElementByID() you could instead use querySelector('#ElementID') the mentioned function takes a css selector.

Regarding the style changes, you could use classList and use CSS classes to apply styles and remove them.  However the method you are using is perfectly acceptable.  You could instead use a function to toggle the visibility.  You will also want to spell "visible" correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might use `document.querySelector()` using Native JavaScript

```
Ex: document.querySelector("#Img1");
```

OR

[jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)(If you are open to)

```
for (var i = 1; 1 < sliderImg; i++ ) {
   flickrDisplay[i] = $("#Img1" + (i + 1)); //Same as flickrDisplay[i] = document.getElementById("img" + (i + 1));
   $("#identifer" + i).css('visibility ','visible'); //Same as document.getElementById("identifer" + i).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

NOTE: If you are really concerned about the performance. You should go for `document.getElementById(id)` instead of `$("#id")`

[getElementById VS jQuery('#id')](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44)

Comment: If it is to use `document.querySelector("#Img1")`, use `document.getElementById("Img1")`. Which is a lot faster and supported even by IE5.5.